# Adding custom class version to document

Tags: documentclass, versions

I like to add the version information of my documentclass to the document.

```latex
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/27 v1.12 MyClass]
```

In the PDF: 2022/10/27 v1.12 MyClass

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\csname ver@myclass.cls\endcsname
```